# JavaScript/ jQuery for Closing Browser FireFox / Chrome / IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I need JavaScript / jQuery  code for closing  browser's (  FireFox / Chrome and IE..)

As I have try with
`window.close()`.

But it only work for IE.

Is any other way..?

Comment: you can close the page, not the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can check Browser and write respective script for IE / FireFox

IE---->

```
window.close()
```

FireFox --->

```
var answer = confirm("Do you want to close this window ?");
 if (answer){

netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalBrowserWrite');
    window.close();
 }
 else{
     stop;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for IE and Chrome. (window.close() worked for IE, then win.close for chrome)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CloseThis() {
             var win = window.open('', '_self');
             window.close();
             win.close(); return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Works for me, in Chromium portable!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible as javascript can only interact with the pages rendered by the browser, not the actual browser.

Answer (score 2):

Windows can only be closed by scripts (window.close()) that were opened by scripts in the first place. So generally, this isn't possible (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close)

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
window.close()
```

Comment: From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close): "This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open method. If the window was not opened by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript Console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script."